# JQ: replace an array element, based on subelement value

Tags: json, string, replace, jq

I want to modify the value of `DOMAIN_DISABLE` to true if `DOMAIN` equals `domain1.com`

```sh
jq 'if .DATA[].DOMAIN == "domain1.com" then .DATA[].DOMAIN_DISABLE = true else . end' "${Json}"
```

Json Array:

```json
{
    "ACTION": "domain.list",
    "DATA": [
        {
            "TYPE": "slave",
            "AXFR_IPS": "none",
            "DOMAIN": "domain1.com",
            "TTL_SEC": 0,
            "SOA_EMAIL": "",
            "DOMAINID": 11111,
            "DESCRIPTION": "",
            "EXPIRE_SEC": 0,
            "RETRY_SEC": 0,
            "STATUS": 1,
            "DOMAIN_DISABLE": false,
            "LPM_DISPLAYGROUP": "",
            "REFRESH_SEC": 0
        },
        {
            "TYPE": "slave",
            "AXFR_IPS": "none",
            "DOMAIN": "domain2.net",
            "TTL_SEC": 0,
            "SOA_EMAIL": "",
            "DOMAINID": 22222,
            "DESCRIPTION": "",
            "EXPIRE_SEC": 0,
            "RETRY_SEC": 0,
            "STATUS": 1,
            "DOMAIN_DISABLE": false,
            "LPM_DISPLAYGROUP": "",
            "REFRESH_SEC": 0
        },
        {
            "TYPE": "slave",
            "AXFR_IPS": "none",
            "DOMAIN": "domain3.edu",
            "TTL_SEC": 0,
            "SOA_EMAIL": "",
            "DOMAINID": 33333,
            "DESCRIPTION": "",
            "EXPIRE_SEC": 0,
            "RETRY_SEC": 0,
            "STATUS": 1,
            "DOMAIN_DISABLE": true,
            "LPM_DISPLAYGROUP": "",
            "REFRESH_SEC": 0
        }
    ],
    "ERRORARRAY": []
}
```

Desired output:

```json
{
    "ACTION": "domain.list",
    "DATA": [
        {
            "TYPE": "slave",
            "AXFR_IPS": "none",
            "DOMAIN": "domain1.com",
            "TTL_SEC": 0,
            "SOA_EMAIL": "",
            "DOMAINID": 11111,
            "DESCRIPTION": "",
            "EXPIRE_SEC": 0,
            "RETRY_SEC": 0,
            "STATUS": 1,
            "DOMAIN_DISABLE": true,
            "LPM_DISPLAYGROUP": "",
            "REFRESH_SEC": 0
        },
        {
            "TYPE": "slave",
            "AXFR_IPS": "none",
            "DOMAIN": "domain2.net",
            "TTL_SEC": 0,
            "SOA_EMAIL": "",
            "DOMAINID": 22222,
            "DESCRIPTION": "",
            "EXPIRE_SEC": 0,
            "RETRY_SEC": 0,
            "STATUS": 1,
            "DOMAIN_DISABLE": false,
            "LPM_DISPLAYGROUP": "",
            "REFRESH_SEC": 0
        },
        {
            "TYPE": "slave",
            "AXFR_IPS": "none",
            "DOMAIN": "domain3.edu",
            "TTL_SEC": 0,
            "SOA_EMAIL": "",
            "DOMAINID": 33333,
            "DESCRIPTION": "",
            "EXPIRE_SEC": 0,
            "RETRY_SEC": 0,
            "STATUS": 1,
            "DOMAIN_DISABLE": true,
            "LPM_DISPLAYGROUP": "",
            "REFRESH_SEC": 0
        }
    ],
    "ERRORARRAY": []
}
```

what should I change in my jq command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jq '.DATA |= map(
        if .DOMAIN == "domain1.com"
        then .DOMAIN_DISABLE = true
        else .
        end)' file.json
```

Comment: Could you please add explanation if possible? Also, it was working before the edit too, why did you change it? Also could you please tell what does `|=` means above?

Comment: I understand that `|=`, this is update assignment but we don't need to update DATA but just `.DOMAIN_DISABLE`, so why do we use it before?

Comment: But we need to stay in the context of each element of DATA, which the `map` does. Otherwise, you can't check the DOMAIN.

Comment: Thanks! And could you also tell about `|=`

Comment: It's the update-assignment. It will run the map for each element of .DATA and replace the element by the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
.DATA |= map((.DOMAIN == "domain1.com") as $disable | .DOMAIN_DISABLE |= $disable)
```

This will change `.DATA` whilst keeping everything else in place. Same for each `.DOMAIN_DISABLE` to which we assign the result of  `.DOMAIN=="domain1.com"`.

Comment: This implements a different requirement, and indeed does not produce the "expected" output.

Comment: @peak I'm not sure I understand. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Your program unconditionally changes .DOMAIN_DISABLE, whereas the stated requirements (with which the OP's shown "expected" output agrees) only envision a conditional update. See also @choroba's solution.

Comment: @peak I see but the output _is_ the same though right?

Comment: @peak I ran my program and @choroba's and both give the same result. I get that the I'm unconditionally setting `.DOMAIN_DISABLE` but apart from that the output is the same. No trying to be difficult here but I'm really not seeing what you're trying to get at. Would appreciate if you could shed some lights.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that simply assigns `true` to a `select`ed set of targets. This works (the original object remains in context) because the selection (on the left-hand side) happens in a subcontext (in parentheses) while the assignment itself is still part of the top-level context.

```sh
jq '(.DATA[] | select(.DOMAIN == "domain1.com")).DOMAIN_DISABLE = true'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ig4NgYQDcT)